# How to animate a jquery function passed by parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a simple function in jquery that can animates o rotates an element. My current code is this:

```
<button id="bt_Employment2" name="bt_Employment2" onclick="rotate('bt_Employment2')">

function rotate(elem)
{
    elem.rotate({animateTo:180});     
}
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a string to your rotate function. A string object doesn't contain a rotate function. Use jQuery's $ to get the element with that ID and it should work (didn't test it).

```
<button id="bt_Employment2" name="bt_Employment2" onclick="rotate('#bt_Employment2')">

function rotate(elem)
{
    $(elem).rotate({animateTo:180});     
}
```

Another way could by this:

```
<button id="bt_Employment2" name="bt_Employment2" onclick="rotate(this)">

function rotate(elem)
{
    elem.rotate({animateTo:180});     
}
```